# How to throw multiple alerts in validations in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, typescript

I am trying to validate the form, and each form value is having its own validation criteria. And I need to throw the message of each validation which is failing as alert. I am able to do so, but I am getting that in same line. But I need to put the each sentence in different line.

[image]

I am able to get the correct answer in my console (i.e each error in different line).

I am validating each validation criteria and pushing the errors from each validation in an array. If array is non empty i.e if we are having an error. It will return that error array else go on submit that details to backend API.

```
if(errors.length != 0){
      console.log("Not an empty array");
      console.log(errors.join('\r\n'));
      this.errorMsg = errors.join('\r\n');
    }else{
      this.service.createData(formData).subscribe((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        this.userForm.reset();
        this.successMsg = res.message;
      });
    }
```

.html

```
<div *ngIf="errorMsg" class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
        <strong>{{errorMsg}}</strong> 
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: I suspect this is not a native alert but some HTML-box. Try `<br>`  instead of `\r\n`.

Comment: I am implementing this logic in Angular .ts module and passing that errorMsg in the .html file. whereas this logic is showing correct/expected result in console.

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: @Michel Do you mean something like this `this.errorMsg = errors.join('<br>');` ?

Comment: That's what I meant, yes.

Comment: No thats not working, in the alert pop-up it ts giving the two sentences wit <br> in between them

Comment: I added .html snippet too in the edits

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is you're merging all errors into one `errorMessage`. But, you have to do is iterate and show an alert for each error. So, it'd be something like:

```html
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert" *ngFor="let error of errors">
  <strong>{{errorMsg}}</strong> 
  <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
</div>
```